# accessing toString() non-meber function inside of own class

Tags: c++

accessing non member function

i havent tried too much other than writing (this operator) differently, i think maybe using a friend, but im not exactly familiar with them and not sure if thats what its for, i wanted to see what other have to say, it seems like a pretty simple thing todo.

```
IntSet::IntSet(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e){
  this->data = new bool[this->MAXSETVAL];
  insertElement(a);
  insertElement(b);
  insertElement(c);
  insertElement(d);
  insertElement(e);
}
IntSet::~IntSet(){

}
void IntSet::insertElement(int n){ this->data[n] = true; }
void IntSet::deleteElement(int n){ this->data[n] = false; }
std::string IntSet::toString() const{
  std::vector<char> vect;
  vect.push_back('{');
  for (int i = 0; i < getMax(); i++)
    if (this->data[i] == true) {
      if (i < 10){
        vect.push_back(i + 48);
        vect.push_back(',');
        vect.push_back(' ');
      }else if (i < 100){
        vect.push_back((i / 10) + 48);
        vect.push_back((i % 10) + 48);
        vect.push_back(',');
        vect.push_back(' ');
      }else if (i > 100){
        vect.push_back(i / 100  + 48);
        vect.push_back(i % 100 / 10  + 48);
        vect.push_back(i % 10  + 48);
        vect.push_back(',');
        vect.push_back(' ');
      }
      if (i + 1 == getMax())
        vect.push_back('}');
    }
  char arr[vect.size()];
  for (int i = 0; i < vect.size(); i++)
    arr[i] = vect[i];
  return std::string(arr);
 }



bool equals(const IntSet &Set) {
  // PROBLEM HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  std::string str = (*this)->toString();
  if (str.compare(Set.toString()))
    return true;
  return false;
}
```

Error:

```
IntSet.cpp: In function ‘bool equals(const IntSet&)’:
IntSet.cpp:55:23: error: invalid use of ‘this’ in non-member function
   std::string str = (*this)->toString();
                   ^
```

Comment: The error is telling you that `equals()` is not a member function of a class, so it has no `this` parameter (but even if it did, using `(*this)->` is wrong, unless the class has an overloaded `operator->`, use `this->` instead, or simply omit `this->` altogether when inside a member function). Perhaps you meant to quality your `equals()` implementation as `bool IntSet::equals(const IntSet &Set) const` instead?

Comment: @RemyLebeau its a typo . the carrot is suppose to be under the (*this), i double checked, i also tried the this that way and without. altho i did mean to IntSet::equals, THANK YOU!

Comment: Then I'm voting to close this post as just a typographical error, unless you are still having other problems with it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau i mean not with this specific topic, alto my toString() func isnt printly properly... i mean it is, but instead of {1,2,3} i sometimes get {1,2,3}@H or something wierd at the end.

Comment: That is because you are not null-terminating the `char[]` array that you construct the `std:::string` from. Also, you don't need the `char[]` array at all (besides, the way you are allocating it is non-standard anyway), you can construct the `std::string` from the `std::vector` data directly, then you don't need a null terminator. For that matter, you don't actually need the `std::vector` at all, either. `std::string` has its own `push_back()` method.

Comment: @RemyLebeau loveley, ill take my chances, i usually figure it out.

Comment: @RemyLebeau or u will in seconds, Thank u kindly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau im working with C++ 3

Comment: There is no such thing as "C++ 3".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201289/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-jacob-burgess).